page numbers missing when chapters are more than one pages
Page numbers are displayed "only" on the first pages of every Chapter of my thesis, but no page numbers on the subsequent pages.
I have used the following preamble:
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\include{filename}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pgfplotsset{ytick style={draw=none}}
\pgfplotsset{xtick style={draw=none}}
\topmargin=0.02cm
\textwidth =  17cm
\textheight = 23cm
\baselineskip=11pt
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.01 pt}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0.01 pt}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.4}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ }

\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{makecell, multirow, tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries} % for bold in table using \small

\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{accents}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{calligra}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\hypersetup{colorlinks, 
    breaklinks,
    linkcolor=red,
    citecolor=red,
    linktocpage=true}
\newtheorem{fig}{figure}[section]
\numberwithin{figure}{section}
\newcommand\norm[1]{\left\lVert#1\right\rVert}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{cor}{Corollary}[thm]
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defn}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{conj}{Conjecture}[section]
\newtheorem{exmp}{Example}[section]
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem*{rem}{Remark}
\newtheorem*{note}{Note}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\graphicspath{{images/}}
\title{Thesis Title page}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

%\frontmatter

\pagestyle{empty}
\clearpage
\begin{center}
\textbf{\large DECLARATION}
\end{center}
\clearpage
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}
\textbf{\large ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS}
\end{center}
\clearpage
\begin{center}
\textbf{\large CERTIFICATE FROM THE SUPERVISOR}
\end{center}

\clearpage

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}
\textbf{\large NOTATIONS}
\end{center}

\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\thispagestyle{empty}}
\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage
\setcounter{page}{1}

\chapter{Introduction}

People say that children are completely empty-headed. So what will be taught, so will learn, so will remember. But in the present time, this popular belief is largely shaken. Most parents complain, My child can't remember. Learning at home or at school, but test scores don't reflect that. Then the children forget!
People say that children are completely empty-headed. So what will be taught, so will learn, so will remember. But in the present time, this popular belief is largely shaken. Most parents complain, My child can't remember. Learning at home or at school, but test scores don't reflect that. Then the children forget!
People say that children are completely empty-headed. So what will be taught, so will learn, so will remember. But in the present time, this popular belief is largely shaken. Most parents complain, My child can't remember. Learning at home or at school, but test scores don't reflect that. Then the children forget!
People say that children are completely empty-headed. So what will be taught, so will learn, so will remember. But in the present time, this popular belief is largely shaken. Most parents complain, My child can't remember. Learning at home or at school, but test scores don't reflect that. Then the children forget!
People say that children are completely empty-headed. So what will be taught, so will learn, so will remember. But in the present time, this popular belief is largely shaken. Most parents complain, My child can't remember. Learning at home or at school, but test scores don't reflect that. Then the children forget!
People say that children are completely empty-headed. So what will be taught, so will learn, so will remember. But in the present time, this popular belief is largely shaken. Most parents complain, My child can't remember. Learning at home or at school, but test scores don't reflect that. Then the children forget!
People say that children are completely empty-headed. So what will be taught, so will learn, so will remember. But in the present time, this popular belief is largely shaken. Most parents complain, My child can't remember. Learning at home or at school, but test scores don't reflect that. Then the children forget!
People say that children are completely empty-headed. So what will be taught, so will learn, so will remember. But in the present time, this popular belief is largely shaken. Most parents complain, My child can't remember. Learning at home or at school, but test scores don't reflect that. Then the children forget!
People say that children are completely empty-headed. So what will be taught, so will learn, so will remember. But in the present time, this popular belief is largely shaken. Most parents complain, My child can't remember. Learning at home or at school, but test scores don't reflect that. Then the children forget!
People say that children are completely empty-headed. So what will be taught, so will learn, so will remember. But in the present time, this popular belief is largely shaken. Most parents complain, My child can't remember. Learning at home or at school, but test scores don't reflect that. Then the children forget!
\chapter{Prelimineries}
People say that children are completely empty-headed. So what will be taught, so will learn, so will remember. But in the present time, this popular belief is largely shaken. Most parents complain, My child can't remember. Learning at home or at school, but test scores don't reflect that. Then the children forget!


\chapter{Main chapter 1}
\section{aa}
\section{bb}
\chapter{Main chapter 2}
\section{aa}
\section{bb}
\chapter{Main chapter 3}
\section{aa}
\subsection{aaa}
\section{bb}
\subsection{bbb}
\chapter{Main chapter 4}
\section{aa}
\subsection{aaa}
\section{bb}
\subsection{bbb}
\chapter{Main chapter 5}
\section{aa}
\subsection{aaa}
\section{bb}
\subsection{bbb}
\section{cc}

\end{document}

The outcome pdf is here
You will see page numbers are displayed only on the first pages of every Chapter but not on the subequent pages. For exaple, page number missing at page 2 of the "Introduction" Chapter.
In the above preamble, I want to highlight the following especial part regarding "Table of Contents":
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\thispagestyle{empty}}
\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage
\setcounter{page}{1}

\chapter{Introduction}

Maybe something happeing here. But I coulnt't find the issue.
Thanks

\pagestyle{empty} has effect on all pages after it. Use \thispagestyle{empty} instead.

@Stephen, thanks. It worked.
